# Cleaning the cell of any special characters, multiple occurences

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, search, replace, cell

I have an interesting problem that I haven't found elsewhere. In VBA/Excel I could do it, but after switching to Google/Sheets I am lost :-).
I need to use Google AppScript in Google Sheets to clean one cell from special characters that I have as a list defined on another sheet (one column, but I don't know how many characters (=rows) will be listed there, the list may expand).I want to replace these characters (e.g. ".", ",", "-", "_", etc.) in one particular cell with a space so that I can then easily split the cleaned text into words. These characters can occur multiple times in this one cell.
Any ideas? Thanks for the tips!

Comment: try replacing this set `[,.,-_ ]` with space using /g regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert `(e.g. ".", ",", "-", "_", etc.)` with a space using Google Apps Script.
- The values are one column.

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const search = [".", ",", "-", "_"];
  const replace = " ";

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(`[${search.map(e => "\\" + e).join("")}]`).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(replace);
}
```

- In this sample script, the values of column "A" are converted. Please modify the column letter for your situation.
- For example, if you want to convert `...` to   which is the one space, please modify `[${search.map(e => "\\" + e).join("")}]` to `[${search.map(e => "\\" + e).join("")}]+`.

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: Thank you for inspiration. I modified the code a little as I wanted to change the content of just one cell, but the characters to be replaced were defined on a different sheet. This did the trick for me:
const spreadsheetSymbols = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Symbols");
var search = spreadsheetSymbols.getRange("A2:A" + spreadsheetSymbols.getLastRow()).getValues();
var replace = " ";
spreadsheet.getRange("B3").createTextFinder(`[${search.map(e => "\\" + e).join("")}]`).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(replace);

Comment: @Pavel Dolejš Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.